# how to change the look of a citation call-out

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using `apalike`. When I cite a book with two authors, A and B, instead of having (A and B)  it compiles it as (A/B)

```
@book{Keefe1997-KEEVAR,
    publisher = {MIT Press},
    author    = {Rosanna Keefe and Peter Smith},
    title     = {Vagueness: A Reader},
    year      = {1997},
}
```

in the text I write:

```
 (Keefe / Smith 1997)
```

How can I change it to (keefe and Smith 1997) or (Keefe & Smith 1977)?

Comment: Welcome, just the bib entry is not enough to properly help you. A minimal working example is needed. Are you *really* writing `(Keefe / Smith 1997)` in your document directly? If so, you are in charge of properly citing. Or are you using `\cite{Keefe1997-KEEVAR}`  like anybody would do?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package -- and load the `apalike` bibliography style via the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`, right? -- I suggest you proceed as follows:

- issue the directive `\setcitestyle{aysep={}}` immediately after loading `natbib`, and
- use the `\citep` directive to generate "parenthesis-style" citation call-outs.

Of course, be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to generate the bibliography and all citation call-outs.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{Keefe1997-KEEVAR,
    publisher = {MIT Press},
    author = {Rosanna Keefe and Peter Smith},
    title = {Vagueness: A Reader},
    year = {1997}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}} % no comma between author(s) and year
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\citep{Keefe1997-KEEVAR}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```